# c++ : static const initialization order

Tags: c++11, static

I have a problem with initializing static const fields in proper order. I want first initialize my directions and then a vector of them:

file Direction.hh:

```
class Direction {
public:

  static const Direction LEFT;
  static const Direction RIGHT;
  static const Direction UP;
  static const Direction DOWN;
  int x_,y_;
  char code_;
  Direction(const int x,const int y,const char c) : x_(x), y_(y), code_(c) {}
  Direction(const Direction& d) : Direction(d.x_, d.y_, d.code_) {}
private:
  Direction() {x_ = y_ = 0; code_ = ' ';}
};
```

file Direction.cc:

```
const Direction Direction::LEFT(-1,0,'L');
const Direction Direction::RIGHT(1,0,'R');
const Direction Direction::UP(0,1,'U');
const Direction Direction::DOWN(0,-1,'D');
```

main program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include "Direction.hh"

const std::vector<Direction>  move_order({Direction::UP,Direction::RIGHT,Direction::DOWN,Direction::LEFT});

int main(void) {

  for(const Direction & d : move_order)  std::cerr << d.code_<<" ";
}
```

The code above is just a synthetic example  behaving as my real (much longer) code. So I would appreciate a general solution for the problem rather than advices how to fix this particular program. My goal is to rewrite a large Java library to C++. Such a pattern is used there several times. And in Java it works because LEFT or UP are properly initialized by a static initializer block when the class is loaded.

I would expect this code to print "U R D L", but it prints "    " instead which suggest me that the fields are not initialized. This is quite puzzling to me because I intentionally made the default constructor private to avoid such empty initialization.

**ANSWER**

Insipred by Michael Burr's comments, I searched for [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/static-init-order.html) and learned that I should replace a variable with a method. In my implementation this looks like:

```
const std::vector<Direction> & move_order() {
    static const std::vector<Direction> moves({Direction::UP,Direction::RIGHT,Direction::DOWN,Direction::LEFT});
return moves;
}
```

and now the program works just as expected

Comment: You should be fine as long as the definitions of the constants are in the same TU as the definition of the copy constructor: intialization must complete before the first function in the TU is called, and your vector initialization calls the copy constructor.

Comment: Well, I added explicit copy constructor to the example code and when I execute it, it does not print "U R D L" as I want. It prints just the spaces showing that the objects in the vector are not initialized properly. I've also added one more question to my post.

Comment: How are you compiling you program? If you've forgotten to compile Direction.cc, it may cause this behaviour without any compiler errors because everything is already properly defined in your header file (i.e. no undefined references would show up). Just a thought, as I know you said this is a _synthetic example_.

Comment: You have an unspecified ordering between when the ctor for `move_order` is called and the ctors for the various static `Direction` objects are called since two different translation units are involved. It looks like the `move_order` ctor is being called first.  You'll need to look into the general solutions/alternatives  for the C++ static object initialization order problem - I'm sure there are several topics on So about this already.

Comment: @tnorgd: You have defined the copy constructor inline, so it's not uniquely defined in the TU that defines the static member constants. Try changing it to not be defined inline.